# Twit listen for mentions, but ignore replies

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am developing a twitter bot. One main feature is that it needs to listen for when it gets mentioned. I am doing that with this code:

```
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: @ExampleName });
stream.on('tweet', tweeted);
```

However, the function tweeted still gets called when one of @ExampleName's tweets gets responded to.

This is because twitter automatically mentions the user you respond to when replying.

Is there anyway I could make it ignore responses, and only listen for mentions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The legacy Twitter streaming API does not provide for more complex queries when using the `track` keyword, so you would have to do that filtering out yourself inside the tweeted function to decide if this was a mention or a response / reply.

In the new v2 Filtered Stream, you could create a [rule](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/integrate/build-a-rule) that explicitly excludes replies to Tweets from the user. For example in your case you could have a rule of `@ExampleName -is:reply`. At the moment, the `twit` library does not support v2, but there are some alternatives, as well as [sample code](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/master/Filtered-Stream/filtered_stream.js).